# JWT in Angular not playing nice -- getting invalid header error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, header, jwt

I am just hardcoding a JWT for testing purposes but these two lines in my angular app are getting me the following error:

Code:

```
this.localStorageService.set("jwt", "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImltYy1hcGkifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJWVFAgQVBJIiwiaWF0IjoxNDYzNDI0Njk2LLJqdGkiOiJ6ckEyN2lOcGhsUi1Wdkl1VGZPWFNRIiwib3JnYW5pemF0aW9uSWQiOiIxIiwidXNlck5hbWUiOiJ0ZXN0VXNlciIsInVzZXJJZCI6IjEifQ.xWe_TK6F9t6hCMm7KB8WNy5HmUkiWJRIRZg0POjMuzyL8VjRSe9aWREqdHWvu6nqOv8Sfm5RsC7lrB3inqjE4Tim0Njy52Wxa9FuYllz11qmce6QSquti2hfHu6Trfzosiwl54y8cBfgm2VlLWIb2ukinJhcxCr8-rJzfK4hM9R-cgI-​_Yd459JDmNj0HeJ-UlP9fIiCX71YZGEVag8Nqg9bdsSgTqmJQ3667W_p_vyPK1P1whvhFBGUydXjZRk_W01pgr2AON3N_​-EmzJAo7t1J0Rll0BxB4aQXTNdX1vmhoNllqcr81ZxC-5k77-Eci-4gaWY9fLG7ADR872jKog");
this.$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = String(this.localStorageService.get("jwt"));
```

Error:

```
Error: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImltYy1hcGkifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJSVFAgQVBJIiwiaWF0IjoxNDYzNDI0Njk2LCJqdGkiOiJ6ckEyN2lOcGhsUi1Wdkl1VGZPWFNRIiwib3JnYW5pemF0aW9uSWQiOiIxIiwidXNlck5hbWUiOiJ0ZXN0VXNlciIsInVzZXJJZCI6IjEifQ.xWe_TK6F9t6hCMm7KB8WNy5HmUkiWJRIRZg0POjMuzyL8VjRSe9aWREqdHWvu6nqOv8Sfm5RsC7lrB3inqjE4Tim0Njy52Wxa9FuYllz11qmce6QSquti2hfHu6Trfzosiwl54y8cBfgm2VlLWIb2ukinJhcxCr8-rJzfK4hM9R-cgI-​_Yd459JDmNj0GeJ-UlP9fIiCX71YZGEVag8Nqg9bCsSgTqmJQ3667W_p_vyPK1P1whvhFBGUydXjZRk_W01pgr2AON3N_​-EmzJAo7t1J0Rll0BxB4aQXTNdX1vmhoNllqcr81ZxC-5k77-Eci-4gaWY9fLG7ADR872jKog' is not a valid HTTP header field value.
```

Not a valid HTTP Header field value. I've tried without String() and angular.fromJson to no avail. 
Anyone run into this/have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance--

Comment: Angular version 1.3.7 - -

Answer (score 1):

We just ran into this issue. The fix for was was we had a bad character in the string...more specifically a carriage return.

Refer to the HTTP 1.1 spec ([section 2.2](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec2.html#sec2.2) and [section 4.2](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2)) for more details.

Briefly looking through your header value I can't find any illegal characters but that's where I would start looking.